# UML for Web Application Interface

Tags: uml

Can someone point out examples on the Web for simple UML diagrams for a web application?

Example - I have a LIST screen that allows the user to change sequence number [one of the columns] and season Type [select drop down in another column]. It has save and cancel buttons for saving the changed values and removing the changes.

What should the activity / sequence and state diagram for the same?

Comment: Your explanation of what they do seems more useful to me than going through UML diagrams. If you really have a complex scenario or algorithm that is harder to discuss about without a higher level abstraction (diagrams) then I will use a diagram..may be UML

Comment: Agree, even for simple scenarios like these, I should be able to put together UML diagrams. I guess my question is more like how to create UML diagrams for Web Application Interfaces?

Comment: I still didn't get it, do you want a UML tool reverse engineering existing code? or do you want to model first/independently of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think UML is the appropriate language to model web application interfaces. In fact the same OMG is now promoting a new standard for this called IFML http://www.ifml.org/